# Select the first div within another div

Tags: html, css

I have a hotell booking site, where user can choose check-in and check-out date in a week view. Each date has a decoration "left border" so that it is easier to see the dates.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">

<h1>Check-in date:</h1>
<div class="dates-wrapper">
    <div class="prev">&larr;</div>
    <div class="date">15 May 2015</div>
    <div class="date">16 May 2015</div>
    <div class="date">17 May 2015</div>
    <div class="next">&rarr;</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both"></div>

<h1>Check-out date:</h1>
<div class="dates-wrapper">
    <div class="prev">&larr;</div>
    <div class="date">15 May 2015</div>
    <div class="date">16 May 2015</div>
    <div class="date">17 May 2015</div>
    <div class="next">&rarr;</div>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.prev, .next, .date  {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;  
}
.date {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.dates-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.content: first-child{
  border-left: none;
}
```

See this example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zvo72tec/

I have spend many hours trying to remove left border for the first day (15 May 2016) for both views (check-in and check-out). My solution with :first-child is not working since div "date" is not direct child of parent "content" div. Appreciate any help!

Is it possible to do it in css?

Comment: don't use a space after the `:` in css. And I've posted the answer to your question.

Comment: @aifrim: I guess that space would mean all direct first-child elements in content-div, but what does it mean without space after the colon in this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use [`:nth-child`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) selectors.

```
.date:nth-child(2) {
    border: none;
}
```

And by the way. The div that encloses the date you want is not the `fist-child` of any element you have there. It's the second child.

The first child of the `.dates-wrapper` elements are those arrows.

Or you can use the [`:nth-of-type`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/)

Comment: ...or `nth-of-type(2)` like so: `.dates-wrapper .date:nth-of-type(2){border-left: none;}`. This is less error-prone in case of adding another elemnts before second `.date` element.

Comment: @Darek or that. but they are all divs.